# Using Law of Sines instead of Law of Cosines...?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is the question:

A ship travels 60 mi due east, then adjusts its course 15 degrees northward. After traveling 80 mi in that direction, how far is the ship from its point of departure?

Now, I know that the angle going upward north is 180-15=165, but my question is when I use the Law of Sines to find that same angle, I get a different answer? 
This is the work:
$\frac{\sin(15)}{80}=\frac{\sin(x)}{60}$, then $x=11.2$, so $180-15-11.2=153.8$ which is not equal to 165...?

I got $165$ from a solution, but now that I think about it how can I have 165 if I already have 15 for one of the angles and 165+15=180, but the angles of a triangle have to equal 180, so my last angle would be zero?

Comment: What makes you think the angle opposite the side of length $80$ is $15$? You have a side-angle-side relationship. The law of cosines is a better fit.

Comment: @user69810 The way I drew it, the ship travels northward 80mi and this is with the adjusted direction...I don't know how to post my picture up here

Comment: You have a side of length $60$, an angle of $165$ degrees and a side of length $80$. The side opposite the $165$ degree angle gives you the distance.

Comment: @user69810 Oh okay, got it, I drew my diagram incorrectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't know that the angle opposite the 80 mi is 15 degrees. This is not given in the question. I think what you're forgetting is that the 15 degree angle is *outside* the triangle, but you used that angle to find the 165 degrees?